# MYSQL translate escaped HEX liked string to human readable

Tags: mysql, sql

This is supposed to be spanish words. I imported the words from a dictonary in txt format. Only spanish one got translated like these. The thing is I cant search for a word. It does not find anything.
How can I convert these in `mysql` to human readable and searchable `string`?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `es_words` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=660099 ;

INSERT INTO `es_words` (`id`, `word`, `user`) VALUES
(1, 'ÿþa\0\r\0', 0),
(2, '\0a\0-\0\r\0', 0),
(3, '\0a\0a\0r\0ó\0n\0i\0c\0o\0\r\0', 0),
(4, '\0a\0a\0r\0o\0n\0i\0t\0a\0\r\0', 0),
(5, '\0a\0b\0a\0\r\0', 0),
(6, '\0a\0b\0a\0b\0a\0\r\0', 0),
(7, '\0a\0b\0a\0b\0i\0l\0l\0a\0r\0s\0e\0\r\0', 0),
(8, '\0a\0b\0a\0b\0o\0l\0\r\0', 0),
(9, '\0a\0b\0a\0c\0á\0\r\0', 0),
(10, '\0a\0b\0a\0c\0a\0l\0\r\0', 0),
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know very many Spanish words but looking at the strings in your example it would seem that the words have null characters (\0) and some carriage returns (\r) inserted seemingly at random between each letter.  It would be better to clean up whatever generated your insert query rather than trying to clean up the database after the fact I think.

That being said this query will allow you to search and display human readable values.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT REPLACE(word, '\0', '') as fixedword from es_words) as t
WHERE fixedword LIKE '%aaronita%'
```

You could also use the results of the above query to clean the values in the table but I think I would focus on trying to find out where the '\0' and '\r' are coming from in the insert statement.